# bezierCurveTo() with Custom Scroll Path Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, path, scroll

I'm using the jQuery plugin: Custom Scroll Paths from https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath. I see that they have added functionality for bezierCurveTo, but it is not working very well. The path is drawn incorrectly. Could someone please help me out?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you put your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi sjy, thanks for helping. Here is the jsfiddle:[link]http://jsfiddle.net/ncoetzer/fYrFT/

Comment: @sjy - The code I'm referring to is from line 214 - 270.

Comment: Anyone any idea / help?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Did you solve the problem? The jsfiddle link seems to be to the code for the plugin you're using, not the code you wrote yourself. If you send me a jsfiddle link for the code you wrote, I'll see if I can work out why it's broken.